# How sites like Badoo are using Nearby geolocation search?

Tags: laravel, geolocation

How applications like `Badoo.com` are using Nearby geolocation search?
I want to make smth similar, like user is clicking on "Search", that is turning on his geolocation, and then in some range, for example `1km` is finding for another users.

I mean, how should it work ? From my point of view, when user is clicking Search, using google maps API to retrieve longitude and latitude of user, and send it to the database. Next, make an `AJAX request` to DB to find all users that are in range of 1km from that coordinates and fetch the results.

I think I'm not right at all. Can someone explain that logic from A-Z and what services/scripts to use to achieve it ?
Thanks!

Comment: So basically this would do it https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?hl=fr

Comment: @ka_lin, did you undestand me correctly? I mean it's an application of hundreds of people that wanna meet each other. I want to turn on the "radar" and find persons that are in specific radius from me.

Comment: Who will be the consumer? (web, native android )
Android: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html
Browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation Laravel will be your API

Comment: I have an iOS based application (front), and I am writing the back-end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue but I was trying to find closest featured ads compared to the user location, I've wrote this piece of code:

```
$userAddress = GeoLocation::fromDegrees($request->latitude, $request->longitude);

$geocode = GeoLocation::getGeocodeFromGoogle($address);
$latitude = $geocode->results[0]->geometry->location->lat?:24.55; //Here I was taking only first match
$longitude = $geocode->results[0]->geometry->location->lng?:24.55; //Here I was taking only first match

$placeAddress = GeoLocation::fromDegrees($latitude, $longitude);
$km = $userAddress->distanceTo($placeAddress, 'km');
$meters = floatval(number_format($km*1000, 2, '.', ''));

...

/**
 * Showing 5 featured
 *
 * Sorts and returns only 5 of the elements
 * from list.
 *
 * @param $list
 * @return Illuminate\Support\Collection
 */
 private function calculateShortest($list) {
     return $list->sortBy(function($val, $key) {
         return $val->km;
     })->take(5);
 }
```

This might help you get an idea how to calculate the distances..I've removed a lot of code thats not relevant, but I think you will get an idea. Here is the code for [GeoLocation class](https://pastebin.com/wKi6UtfW)

**Flow:** You should first get longitude and latitude of the location that user selects as his `home` address, then save it in the database. Then when someone tries to find a `match` you can calculate boundaries based off of their `longitude and latitude of home address` and `radius` and then by those boundaries you can query the database, or you can narrow the search more, by `gender, status, etc.`

Comment: But from steps, how should it all work? I mean...determine the current user location via JS, and then use this longitude and latitude for query in DB? If so, how to determine/save/edit other users geolocation and show relevant dates? 
How does all this process look by steps, for a better understanding of idea, first?
Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer with the flow

Comment: Thanks, much better now. What you used to determine in front the longitude and latitude of user, so that values will be stored in DB? <br>
But, this app is basically desired to works every time, not just based on the same location. May be it will be a better idea to search by online users? Or on each time that every user turns on the geolocation to update his coordonates?

Comment: You can use their current geolocation too, it all comes down how you implement it, but the flow is the same